# How to insert an image between a Toolbar and a TabLayout?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-toolbar, android-appbarlayout

I would like to insert an image(the blue imageView) in my AppBarLayout between a Toolbar and a TabLayout. The TabLayout should always be displayed and the Toolbar when you scroll up. The image should only be displayed when you scroll to the top of the page.
However, I have the problem that the image always blocks or obstructs the top toolbar. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem?

Code:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Site.MainPage">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainPage_appBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/mainPage_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/UpperToolbarBackground"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mainPage_toolbar_title"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionToolBar.Title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Test"
                android:textColor="@color/UpperToolbarText" />


        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/mainPage_profile_picture"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:background="@color/blue_700"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/mainPage_tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="noScroll"
            app:tabMode="auto" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/mainPage_nestedScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/mainPage_appBar">


        <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:id="@+id/mainPage_viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true" />

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Example Images:

#### How it is:

Start

[image]

Scroll down

[image]

Scroll a little bit up (here is the problem)

[image]

#### How it is supposed to be:

[image]

Comment: In your case does view pager also has a scrolling content?

Comment: Yes. In this case(for testing) it's a TextView in a NestedScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [Material Design App Bar](https://material.io/components/app-bars-top).

I think your are trying to create a prominent top app bar and also want to use image in the bar.

The article explains pretty much everything. But in case you have any trouble do ask.

Comment: I tried it again with a CollapsingToolbarLayout, but that didn't work either. Unfortunately I didn't find my problem at the link :/